# How to use Android native component like Broadcast receiver in react native application?

Tags: android, react-native

How to use android native component like Broadcast receiver in react native application?
I am trying to use android native component like broadcast receiver or service in react-native application?

Comment: create a native bridge https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: thanks @AnkitAman. i have one question that do you about other android native component development . in given URL they are giving only Toast message display .

Comment: you can try this https://brightinventions.pl/blog/write-native-in-react-native/ . I find this on google. But looks similar implementation.